# Western Digital Passport Drive Shows up on Old 2009 MacBook Pro, but not my new one

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, external-disk

I just bought a new MacBook Pro to replace my old 2009 model. For some strange reason, the external Western Digital Passport Drive I've used for Time Machine on my old Mac doesn't seem to work on the new one.

No icon shows up on the desktop. Disk Utilities doesn't show the disk. I've tried it in all three USB ports. No luck.

It *sometimes* shows up in system reports. When I plug the drive into a USB port, I get information from the Console App:

> `9/16/14 9:32:13.000 PM kernel[0]: The USB device Apple Internal Keyboard /     Trackpad (Port 5 of Hub at 0x14000000) may have caused a wake by issuing a remote wakeup (2)`

Dead Drive? No, it works just fine on my older MacBook Pro 2009 model.

The only thing I can think of is that my older model had USB 2 ports while the newer Mac uses USB 3 ports. The port on my drive is a USB 3 port. Maybe formatting the drive via USB 2 makes it impossible to use for USB 3?

---

#### One More Thing...

I didn't mention this earlier because I forgot. Whoops.

The drive is encrypted, and I need a password to open it. On my old MacBook, if I hold down the *option* key while booting, I can put in a password for the drive, and I see the various partitions (There is the TimeMachine partition, a Yosemite Beta partition, and a Yosemite Emergency Boot Partition).

If I put this on my 2009 MacBook Pro, it simply shows up. If I put this on my wife's iMac (2012), I have to put in the password, but it mounts fine.

On my new MacBook Pro, I don't see it (or am I offered an option to enter a password) if I hold down the *option* key when I boot the system.

Also, a question came up about the OS:

The old MacBook is running a beta of Yosemite. It was running Mavericks and it would be the same release and version of the one on the new MacBook Pro. However, the drive crashed, and I was forced to initialize and format, and install Yosemite since that's the only emergency boot item I had.

It's the reason I decided I needed a new MacBook Pro. The new MacBook Pro and my wife's iMac are both running the same version of Mavericks. The old MacBook Pro *was* running the same version of Mavericks and using the WD disk before it crashed.

This isn't a terrible emergency. I had put my Documents folder on Dropbox, so all of my documents were backed up to Dropbox. Other docs were in iCloud. Almost all of my apps were from the Mac App store (except for some open source tools). My mail is IMAP. The only thing on the WD I didn't have were iPhotos that weren't in iCloud. (Which makes me wonder if Time Machine is still all that important).

Comment: It does not look like it thinks it is a drive, it thinks it is a keyboard/trackpad? AFAIK the USB 3 is backward compatible to USB 2.

Comment: Occasionally, it shows up on the system report, but most of the time, it doesn't. Doesn't even show the port as having anything in it.

Comment: If you have not solved it by now, I would guess it is the cable.

Comment: I'll see if I can dig up another USB 3 cable and give it a try. Strange that it works with one on a constant basis, but not the other.

Comment: Just read you other replay wrt Old Mac and Yosemite Beta on it. Do not know enough about OS 10.10 to tell you if that is a problem. Try the Target Disk mode to see if you now can access it.

Comment: Yeah, target disk mode! I'll boot up the old Mac in Target disk mode and connect the two machines with FireWire. Hmm... Not on my new Mac. Thunderbolt? Not on the old Mac... Spend $30 on Thunderbolt/Firewire cable? Apple doesn't recommend it for Target Disk Mode. Target mode was the first thing I thought of too, but suddenly realized that the two machines had different ports. Life is fun. Ended up doing it the old fashion way: USB Stick Drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cable is bad. It works in USB2 devices, but not USB3 devices. I took it to the Genius Bar, and using that cable in a new MacBook Air had the same problems. The Genius Bar had a USB3 cable, and using that one worked. Unfortunately, Apple Stores don't sell USB cables, so I have to see if I can round one up.

Comment: I found a USB 3.0 cable at a local shop for $5. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Are both MacBooks running the same version of Mavericks? WD had a fiasco with their applications, kernel extensions, etc. being incompatible with Mavericks, which led to massive customer data loss. You might need to update the drive's firmware and erase every trace of WD SmartWare, etc. on the drive and possibly even on the new MacBook, as their crapware can self-install in some instances.

Comment: Funny story there... My 2009 MacBook had started to act a bit flaky. Keyboard and trackpad weren't as responsive, and the drive was acting up. My original plan was to buy a new MacBook Pro once Yosemite was released. Old MacBook Pro internal drive crashed, and I ended up reinitializing it and installing Yosemite Beta. So no, they're not running the "same version of Mavericks". I know about crapware, and initialized the WD and reformatted it when I bought it. Still, seems strange it's absolutely blank. The WD is encrypted with Apple's FileVault. Does that do anything?